# Can I install Ubuntu?

Tags: setup, operating-systems, ubuntu

To my understanding, the Raspberry Pi supports Debian. Has anyone had any success running Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Are there any particular features of Ubuntu you would like?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: It's my favorite desktop distribution, so I would have intention to try to stay with it on my new computer as well :)

Comment: Fair enough, I was just going to say a lot of the features can be found on Debian anyway. Unity excluded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [Official FAQ Page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> **What Linux distros will be supported at launch?**
>
> Fedora, Debian and ArchLinux will be supported from the start. We hope
> to see support from other distros later. (Because of issues with newer
> releases of Ubuntu and the ARM processor we are using, **Ubuntu can’t
> commit to support Raspberry Pi at the moment**.) You will be able to
> download distro images from us as soon as the Raspberry Pi is
> released, and we will also be selling pre-loaded SD cards shortly
> after release.

---

#### Edit

It seems that since the launch of Raspberry Pi 2, [Snappy Ubuntu Core](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/snappy) can be run on RP2.

> Thanks to a very successful collaboration between the Raspberry Pi Foundation and Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, we are pleased to announce that Snappy Ubuntu Core is available for the Raspberry Pi 2, the latest Raspberry Pi family member.
>
> -- https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/02/02/snappy-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-2/

However, it should be noted for the anxious that this is **not a desktop version** of Ubuntu.

---

#### Edit #2

It seems that now both Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 support installing Ubuntu. You can find official documentation for installing Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi in [Ubuntu's Developer Documentation](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3).

Comment: Thanks, @Jesse! I'll see if I can update it soon with current information. Or feel free to submit an edit yourself if you'd like. Either way!

Comment: I hope my comment did not sound offensive, my intention was actually to warn people reading the answer, and I forgot that you would be notified. I see now that the comment could easily be taken as offensive from your side :-(

Comment: @Jesse No problem at all! Thanks for the reminder to keep things updated!

Answer (score 8):

Short answer. You cannot currently install Ubuntu.

There is no port for ARMv6. Earlier versions (jaunty, karmic) had limited support.

Comment: some info:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/848154

Answer (score 4):

A community maintained Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install image for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B (RP2). This will NOT work on RP1. Change log current as of 2015-04-06 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

This image was initiated by an employee of Canonical (the company that makes Ubuntu) but he did so on his own personal time.
http://www.finnie.org/2015/02/16/raspberry-pi-2-update-ubuntu-14-04-image-available/

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36378/5538

Comment: This is a forum thread for this RP2 modified Ubuntu distro:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=100553

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on a Raspberry Pi 2. Any Raspberry Pi 1 will not run Ubuntu.

The Pi 2 can run Ubuntu Mate: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2):

As @Merlin04 said, a raspberry pi 2 runs Ubuntu Mate 15.04. However, I've found that the OS by default is a bit heavy and slow at times (videos and audio are really bad).

To combat this, I use the LXDE desktop environment instead of the default Mate environment (`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`); it has very light applications for file-handling, etc. For videos, I use SMPlayer and set the cache size to 20,000 kb.

Aside from these two issues, no complaints :) it works exactly like the normal Ubuntu.

Side note: you can also install Ubuntu Mate 15.04 Core, which is just the command line (~50MB vs ~1.2GB for the full desktop with GUI)