# Chromium OS, is it possible to make it work with Raspberry Pi Model B+?

Tags: chrome-os

Chromium OS, is it possible to make it work with Raspberry Pi Model B+?

I've actually tried it, but it boots upto the rainbow image only, not sure if I need to wait longer but it seems its stuck there already. What am I missing here?

Comment: +1 for being adventurous! According to [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen), the persistence of the rainbow screen suggests `start.elf` has been loaded, but `kernel.img` is failing to boot. What image are you trying to boot from? Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/could-i-turn-a-pi-into-a-diy-chromebox Those answers seem to indicate running Chrome OS is not possible because it hasn't been ported to ARM (the processor architecture used by the Raspberry Pi).

Comment: I'm trying to boot the image described here http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/chromium-os-for-raspberry-pi-2-gets-faster-boot-times-download-now-video-497397.shtml specifically this http://www.mediafire.com/download/rj6bvgearm4i4ye/ChromiumRPI+0.2.img.tar.gz

Comment: Both the link you posted and tsbarnes's link to Reddit say repeatedly "Raspberry Pi 2." While all version of the Pi are similar, they're not all identical. In particular, the Pi 2 processor is ARM7 whereas the previous editions ran an ARM6 processor. While I wasn't able to find anywhere that specifically said it wouldn't work on the B+, I'd be inclined to think it's only built for the Pi 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a project to get it running that just released a beta, you can find it at [/r/ChromiumRPi](http://www.reddit.com/r/ChromiumRPi)

It's more targeting the Pi 2 though, so it likely will run a bit slow.

Comment: It does seem to specifically target the RPi 2 - and if it is related to the Chrome browser THAT will only work to a limited extend on that Pi variant at this time (there are a lot of questions here about people wanting to but being unable to install a recent Chrome on non-RPi2 units...)